# Como valido o pongo la restricción en un combobox en java para que seleccione alguna opción que no sea la que dice "-SELECCIONE-"

Tags: java, netbeans, formularios, validación, jframe

estoy realizando un formulario el cual cuenta con un combobox que tiene como primer item        "-SELECCIONE-" y los otros 12 items son los meses del año, cuando inicio el Formulario obviamente la primera opcion es "-SELECCIONE-" y el punto es que quisiera que cuando el usuario no elija ninguno de los meses del año o items me muestre un mensaje de advertencia ( en un JLabel) diciendo de que debe seleccionar uno de los meses, ya intente con el evento "ItemStateChanged" y "KeyRelease" ademas de usar el metodo equals [ **ComboBoxMeses.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("-SELECCIONE-")** ]

Adjunto imagenes y espero que me puedan ayudar :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que el mensaje de error me quede asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe resaltar que no puedo hacer la verificacion de los datos con el boton registrar ya que este estara desactivado hasta que llene todos los campos. Muchas gracias de antemano y espero que me puedan ayudar, tengan una exelente tarde. Psdata: El lenguaje que estoy usando es Java en Netbeans

Comment: El tema es cuándo refrescar el mensaje de "requerido". Entiendo que debería ser capturando el evento de cambio en el combobox, cuando se ha seleccionado el elemento 0. Inicialmente tendrás que seleccionar el 0 y pintar sí o sí el "requerido". Luego irá cambiando según el usuario vaya seleccionando en el combobox, apareciendo cuando seleccione el elemento 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando se agregan mas opciones al combobox, por defecto se le van asignando el numero de ítem, si tienes 12, por defecto el de la opción seleccione es el item 0, por lo cual puedes hacer una condicional maso menos asi.

```
if (cmbMesesAño.getSelectedIndex()==0){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Seleccione un mes del año");
```

}